# How to change color of swipe to delete button in table view cell

Tags: uitableview

I need to change the color of swipe to delete button from red to my customized color. 
Is this possible?
Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify it. You need to implement your own button. You can add a swipe gesture on the cell and do the animation to show the button. Then handle the button action accordingly.

Comment: @user1448493, Can you please accept, if this helped. There is a tick mark next to the answer.